# Type key duplicate with polymorphic class

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I use spring boot 3.1.2

```
@Data
public class DefaultAccount  extends AbstractAccount{
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, visible = true, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DefaultAccount.class, name = "default")
})
@Data
public abstract class AbstractAccount {

    private String type;

}
```

When I display account, I see type key duplicate

```
{
    "type": "default",
    "type": null
}
```

I done a test, in JsonTypeInfo i changed property for type 2, do same thing in AbstractAccount class and get

```
{
    "type2": "default",
    "type2": null
}
```

seem like jackson duplicate entry, I need to be able to read the value, that why this field is present in the class

Answer (score 0):

You have a 'type' string in your entities that you have left as null; this is completely independent of the property = "type" you have defined as the discriminator for java inheritance, so both are written out.

You do not need and should not have a String type property - each subclass should know what type it is based on the class type of the object. If you must, have each implement a getType method to return the class appropriate type string ie

```
DefaultAccount {
  static final String TYPE = "default";
  public String getType(){ return TYPE ; }
}
```